# Pseudo after causing page flow issues

Tags: html, css

I am having an issue with an `:after` element. I am using it for an underline in a header. For some reason, it is disturbing the flow of the page. Instead of the title being at the top/centered, on my actual page the title is going into the text under it and aligned left.

This is what is looks like:

[image]

I was unable to replicate the issue within a fiddle or snippet, so I was wondering if there is anything within my code that may be causing this. The issue is arising in both Chrome and Firefox.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1ywdan98/)

```css
.section {
 padding: 70px 0;
 height: auto;
 position: relative;
}
.section-wrap {
    margin: 70px 13%;
 position: relative;
 height: auto;
}
.section-main-title-wrap {
 width: 100%;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
}
.section-main-title {
 position: relative;
 color: blue;
 font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
 font-size: 1.8rem;
 width: auto;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: .625rem 0;
 margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.section-main-title:after {
 content: "";
 width: 80%;
 height: 3px;
 background: #489aad;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10%;
}
#home-box-container {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 display: block;
}
.home-box {
 border-right: 2px solid #CDCDCD;
 width: 30%;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 padding: 0 10px;
}
.home-box:last-child {
 border-right: none;
}
.home-box-title, .home-box-description {
 color: #2c2b2c;
 line-height: 1.4em;
}
.home-box-title {
 margin-bottom: 25px;
 font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 700;
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 text-align: center;
}
.home-box-description {
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<section class="section">
   <div class="section-wrap">
    <div class="section-main-title-wrap">
     <header class="section-main-title text-center">HELLO</header>
    </div>
    <div id="home-box-container" class="total-center">
     <div class="home-box">
      <h3 class="home-box-title">Paradigm</h3>
      <p class="home-box-description">
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
      </p>
     </div><div class="home-box">
      <h3 class="home-box-title">Structure</h3>
      <p class="home-box-description">
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
      </p>
     </div><div class="home-box">
      <h3 class="home-box-title">Integration</h3>
      <p class="home-box-description">
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
      </p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: Are you using a 3rd party framework, such as Bootstrap? these might be adding something which affects layout and positioning, which would explain why you can't replicate in a fiddle.

Comment: @Toby No, I am not using any outside framework other than Google fonts.

Comment: @Toby If I provided a url, would that help?

Comment: Do you use any other CSS? E.g. for the `<header>` you set a class *text-center* that is not part of the CSS of your snippet.

Comment: @Marvin Other than my css reset, no.

Comment: A URL would help, yes - at that point it's just a process of elimination to determine what the code at the URL is adding that the fiddle does not include.

Comment: Okay.. so you have the `:after` on `.section-main-title`, shouldn't it be on `.home-box-title` ?

Comment: I have it one `section-main-title` because that is how I am making the underline border.

Comment: You have `position: absolute` set on `.total-center` (div id `home-box-container`), so that is the div being removed from the flow of the document.

Then, you have `width: auto` set on `section-main-title`, set this to 100% to get text centering working (or to have the underline center inside the boundaries of the text, you'll need to set margin-left and margin-right to auto).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136792/discussion-between-toby-and-paul).